# How to open terminal output with a texteditor without the creation of a new file?

Tags: command-line, text-editor

Let's say that I want the output of `ls` viewed in `nano` or `tilde`.

I would do the following:

```
ls >> tmp
nano tmp
rm tmp
```

I don't like this because it creates a dumpfile that I sometimes forget to delete. Some people suggest this:

```
ls | less
```

or

```
ls | more
```

But I cannot do:

```
ls | nano
```

So how to solve this? I would need this especially when it comes to huge terminal outputs like the current processes where I would like to do a search afterwards.

Comment: @steeldriver because I like the text editor `tilde` and the way all the hotkeys are layed out. I can work quickly with that. I have not gotten used to `less` and don't feel the the need to ...

Comment: thank you for your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If viewing with **tilde** is really needed, you may script your idea
Create a function in your `.bashrc`

```
function tildeIt () {
  tmpfile=$(mktemp)
  "$@" > $tmpfile
  tilde $tmpfile
  rm $tmpfile
}

# $@ is all words typed after tildeIt
# mktemp creates a temp file and returns his fullname
```

Reload `.bashrc`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Usage

```
tildeIt command -option
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. Thanks! +1

Comment: Please, teach people to use `mktemp` instead of creating temp filenames with just `$$`.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm supports Monica  : ok, more elegant, i edit

Answer (score 15):

Many programs conventionally use `-` to mean standard input or standard output. Thus, you can open the screen output of a command in nano using `-` as the file name, as in:

```
ls | nano -
```

This will only work if your program does support that convention. This includes `nano` and `vi` on the terminal. Even the graphical text editor `gedit` supports it. However, `pluma` or `mousepad` do not support it, and instead will be instructed to create a regular file named `-`. In other cases, you cannot get around creating a regular intermediate file first.

Comment: This works for me with nano. But when I try it with tilde I get "No such option -"

Comment: This only works if the consuming command explicitly supports it; it's common but far from universal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `vipe`, you can do

```
ls | vipe >/dev/null
```

The program `vipe` (which I believe stands for either vi pipe or view pipe) reads standard in, opens `$EDITOR` on it, and writes whatever is left when you save-and-quit to standard out.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix, everything is a file. Thus, you can read the standard input from a file. In theory that is. Some programs get a bit iffy.

Depending on the editor, you can read /dev/stdin. For example, `cat` works, but gedit complains that /dev/stdin is a special file and can't be edited.

```sh
ls | cat /dev/stdin #works
ls | nano /dev/stdin #doesn't work.
ls | vim /dev/stdin #doesn't work
ls | gvim /dev/stdin #works
```

What works with this method and what doesn't seem to be easily distinguished. So just try it with what you want, and it will either work, or not.

Comment: geany works too with both `geany <(ls -1)` and `ls | geany /dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `bash`, you might try `tilde <( ls )`.

See *Process Substitution* in `bash(1)`.